# Figure out where a method was defined

Tags: ruby

If I follow the following part of [this article](https://www.schneems.com/2016/01/25/ruby-debugging-magic-cheat-sheet.html):

```
    Figure out where a method was defined

    object = Object.new
    puts object.method(:blank?).source_location
    => ["/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.beta1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb", 14]
```

I should be able to find the definition of the `blank?` method, however when I try this code within `irb` with `ruby 2.0.0` I get this error message:

```
    ➜  ~ irb
    irb(main):001:0> object = Object.new
    => #<Object:0x007fc84882f088>
    irb(main):002:0> puts object.method(:blank?).source_location
    NameError: undefined method `blank?' for class `Object'
        from (irb):2:in `method'
        from (irb):2
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Did I miss anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.blank?` method does not exist for a `Object` type. I know for sure it exists for a `String` method if I include the `active_support` lib

```
irb(main):001:0> String.new.method(:blank?).source_location
=> ["/home/xeon/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb", 116]
```

If you include `activesupport-5.0.0.beta1` then it will work for you. (Looking at the source path of the article you have posted)

Comment: Thanks, do you know when it changed? It seems that the author used to work with Object during that time.

Comment: author of that article is using `activesupport-5.0.0.beta1`. I think in this particular version of active support. The blank method exists on Object.